# MySQL Using ORDER BY while using UNION

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to show a list of users where the list of accounts which are `activated=1` are below while `activated=0` accounts are on top. I tried using `UNION` since I need all inactive accounts as `ORDER BY created DESC` while activated accounts set as `ORDER BY email` but for some reason all my `ORDER BY` commands are being ignored. What am I doing wrong here?

```
(
    SELECT 
        email, 
        roles.full role, 
        created 
    FROM sol_users users
    JOIN sol_user_roles ur ON users.id = ur.user_id 
    JOIN sol_roles roles USING(role_id) 
    WHERE activated = 0
    ORDER BY created DESC
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
        email, 
        roles.full role, 
        created
    FROM sol_users users
    JOIN sol_user_roles ur ON users.id = ur.user_id 
    JOIN sol_roles roles USING(role_id) 
    WHERE activated = 1
    ORDER BY email
)
```

Inactive users need to be placed on top so the Admin will know that these need to be activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a union - try:

```
SELECT email, roles.full role, created 
FROM sol_users users
JOIN sol_user_roles ur ON users.id = ur.user_id 
JOIN sol_roles roles USING(role_id) 
ORDER BY activated, case activated when 1 then email end, created DESC
```

Comment: Woah. I never knew you could use conditionals for `ORDER BY`. Such beautiful code!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an `IF` statement in your `ORDER BY` clause. See [this](http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/if-statement-in-order-by-430363.html) for a discussion about a similar topic.